# PHP and Mysql error connection when using require_once() function?

Tags: php, mysql, database

> config.php

```
<?
// Database Constants 
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "gallery");
define("DB_PASS", "phpOTL123");
define("DB_DATABASE", "photo_gallery");
?>
```

> database.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php'); 
class  MySQLDatabase
{
private $connection;
        public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
        }
        }
    }
$database=new MySQLDatabase();
$database->open_connection();  
?>
```

I am defining DB_SERVER and all the other ones as you can see above, but for some reason I get the following errors :

> Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER'
>   (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 6 Database
>   connection failed: mysqli_error()

Comment: Try changing that `<?` in `config.php` to a `<?php`.

Comment: You can also get rid of the trailing `?>`. They don't have any purpose here and can only lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: Also check that you are setting `DB_PASSWORD` and using `DB_PASS`

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Answer (score 2):

PHP short tags are [recommended against](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), because they're usually off.

Thus, your `<?` isn't doing anything, and your database credentials are being treated as plain text instead of PHP. Changing it to the full `<?php` fixes it.